# What is loss exactly?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I'm training the im2txt sample of tensorflow and it outputs the loss:

```
INFO:tensorflow:global step 2174: loss = 3.6930 (15.83 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 2175: loss = 3.6651 (15.52 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 2176: loss = 3.5733 (18.25 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 2177: loss = 3.1979 (18.87 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 2178: loss = 2.9362 (15.99 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 2179: loss = 3.6375 (15.65 sec/step)
```

What is loss? How does it relate to the AI:s probability to perform correctly (is there a formula)? What is ususally an acceptable loss?

Answer (score 6):

From: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py

```
  losses = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=targets,
                                                          logits=logits)
  batch_loss = tf.div(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(losses, weights)),
                      tf.reduce_sum(weights),
                      name="batch_loss")
```

`softmax` is basically a fancy max function that is derivable (you can lookup the exact definition in the docs). It's going to have high values for the largest activations. It can have multiple high activation and this is going to get penalized for all the wrong ones.

Loss is the the thing that you want the model to optimize down.

This doesn't usually mean much unless you've trained lots of similar models with the exact same loss. Usually you look at the loss graph to see when the model stopped making progress so that you can stop training. Also keep in mind that for other models you will want to add other things to the loss that you might want to optimize (say some input weights that you want to average to 1.0) that will bump up the loss but that doesn't mean the model is worse.

If you want to figure out if your model is good or bad add metrics for the things you care about. The obvious things are precision/recall/accuracy. There's predefined metrics already that you can use ([streaming_accuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.metrics/metric_ops#streaming_accuracy)). Alternatively you can compute the metric and add it as a summary but that's not going to be available from the eval dataset.

Another option is to setup a model that's obviously bad (constant or random) and compare the loss of that model with what you are getting.

Answer (score 5):

Loss is the target function that the optimization algorithm will try to minimize.

In general, you want your loss function to be a measure of how bad your model is. But because the optimization algorithms require a few mathematical properties to work nicely, you can't pick the usual stuff like precision and recall (you want continuous functions that are differentiable in relation to the model parameters).

With classification tasks, `softmax` is a common choice. It's a smooth and well-behaved version of `argmax`, which is used to pick the class with highest network activation. With regression, the usual `mean squared error` serves fine.